# Как сделать,чтобы скрипт ждал нового текста?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать,что бы мой скрипт ждал новый текст из кнопки и вводил его в поле,а не брал его в цикле.

```js
<script>
//server side
function change() {
var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 - 10)) + 10;
var rand1 = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 - 10)) + 10;
document.querySelector('.Button.Button--negative.Button--size-m.Button--wide.Button--overflow').textContent="Убрать кнопки | " + rand + " + " + rand1 + " = ?";
}

(function loop() {
    var rand2 = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 1000)) + 1000;
    setTimeout(function() {
            change();
            loop();  
    }, rand2);
}());
//server side
//client side
function matem() {
var ans = document.querySelector('.Button').textContent;
var ots1 = ans.split(' =')[0];
var otv = eval(ots1.split('| ')[1]);
document.querySelector('.ans').value=otv
}

(function loop() {
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (2500 - 500)) + 2500;
    setTimeout(function() {
            matem();
            loop();  
    }, rand);
}());
//client side
</script>
```

```html
<div class="Keyboard__container"><div class="Keyboard__row"><div class="Keyboard__button" style="width: calc(100% - 10px);"><button class="Button Button--negative Button--size-m Button--wide Button--overflow"></button><br><textarea class="ans"></textarea></div></div><div
```